# no later than ~ VS by no later than ~

Tags: prepositions, adverbs, adverbial-phrases

I am familiar with "no later than"". However, I have seen "by no later than".

As far as I know, "no later than" has meaning as follows.

> ​by a particular time and not after it

https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/later_1#later_idmg_2

> by (a specified time) : at, in, on, or before (a specified time)

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/no%2Fnot%20later%20than

.

With regard to this, there are example sentences below.

[image]
https://ludwig.guru/s/by+no+later+than

.

Question 1. is this duplicate meaning with "by"?

Question 2. from what I hear, "no later than time" is a chunk as Adverbial phrase. So is this possible to be with ""by(preposition) + no later than time(Adverbial phrase)""?

Comment: It _is_ rather tautological (saying the same thing twice). Either 'by [date]' or 'no later than [date]' would make sense on their own. Nevertheless, as you have found, 'by no later than' is commonly used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have three equivalent phrases

> by the end of October
> no later than the end of October
> by no later than the end of October

there is no difference in meaning and all of them sound quite natural.